# Em javascript, o que ocorre por baixo desta condição? (3 == '3')

Tags: javascript

Em javascript, o que ocorre por baixo desta condição?

**(3 == '3')**

Comment: Em resumo, o JavaScript converte implicitamente os dados. Faça um teste, tente botar no console as seguintes operações: `3 * '4'`; `true == 1`; `!!null`

Comment: Javascript possui tipagem fraca, ou seja, ele tenta promover tipos para fazer a operação funcionar. No caso, se um tipo é numérico e o outro é string, a string é convertida para número. Se quiser evitar essa conversão, use o operador === , que faz a comparação "forte", em que 3 é diferente de '3'.